# How to make page scrollable with expanded textarea

Tags: html, css

I have a `textarea` and a `submit` button below it.
Right now when I expand the `textarea` so that it goes to the bottom of the page and the submit button disappears.

I can't scroll down for the submit button unless I minimize the page content.

The page is stuck at the top. How do I make the page scrollable when the `textarea` is expanded?

Edit: current code:

```
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder = "title" value="{{title}}">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <textarea type="text" name="note" class = "textarea" placeholder = "note" value="{{note}}"cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" class = "button"value="okay"></div>
    <br>
    <div class = "stat">{{stat}}</div>
</form>
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle or codepen of your code?

Comment: it seems as if you have a rogue </div> above the submit input, the page should have a natural scroll behavior. Have you got any other JS or CSS loading on the page? If you have chrome right click and hit inspect then click console. Refresh the page and tell me if there is any errors

Comment: From what you described, I believe either you need to set body to height:100%; width:100%; or overflow: scroll to whatever div you need. Couldn't understand very clearly.

Comment: @iBrazilian2 That was it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had

```
overflow:hidden;
```

which I changed to

```
overflow:scroll;
```

And that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your DIV css should look like this to get scroller when you expand the textarea.

```
div{
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Thanks